# Python in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time I use input function vsc stops to respond and just doesn't work
It just loads for a long time and then the notification pops out telling me that it took to long to compile and I have to restart program

I tried searching about this problem on Google but I found nothing
On youtube video I saw that the person using vsc could use input normally

Comment: can you post exactly the error?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  It sounds like either a permission issue or a plugin issue.  Millions are using VSCode and I am sure they would complain if this happens to them lots.  Suggest re-install VSCode.  BTW: Though VS Code is catching up. PyCharm is still by far a better IDE for Python debugging than VSCode is (late 2022) I use both daily

Comment: Can you say it in more detail? If you run the code in cmd, whether it will be loaded too long, and whether you use some other extensions. If you only want to run the python file, you need to install only python (it includes jupyter and pylance).